# Multivariate Sample Variance and Covariance

Tags: statistics

When calculating sample variances and covariances from the data matrix, When do we divide by n and when do we divide by n-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your sample is the *population*, divide by n. Otherwise, divide by n-1 because you are losing one degree of freedom in *estimating* mean from the same sample.

For large samples this should make hardly any difference.